# UITextField subview of UIImageView is not responding to touch events

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitextfield, uiresponder

I have a UITextField that responds to touch events when it is added as a subview of self.view.  When I add it as a subview of a UIImageView it does not respond to touch events any more.  I make it a firstResponder and the field is active and takes keyboard input still.  Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [docs for UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) state:

> New image view objects are configured to disregard user events by default. If you want to handle events in a custom subclass of UIImageView, you must explicitly change the value of the userInteractionEnabled property to YES after initializing the object.

Try setting `imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES`

If this doesn't work, I would try adding the UIImageView and the UITextField in a UIView instead. Anyway, this approach seems cleaner.